# Toggle inline CSS in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle some inline CSS with a jQuery script, but I can't do it with a class, because I get the value of the padding-top dynamically, here is the function :

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

var tagsHeight = $('span').outerHeight();

$(".button").click(function (){
  if ($(this).is('active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', '0');
  }
  else if ($(this).not('active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', tagsHeight);
  }
});
```

An a example here : https://jsfiddle.net/o1pbwfuo/

I really don't get why this is not working correctly ...

Thanks !

Comment: This what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/o1pbwfuo/3/

Comment: not a good idea, better toggle class,

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Løvbo Andersen thx mate :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I can't because the value will change with the size of the viewport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your code is due to the incorrect selector in `not()`. That being said, you can improve your logic by combining the `click()` event handlers, then using a single ternary expression to set the `padding-top` on the required element based on the related class. Try this:

```
var tagsHeight = $('span').outerHeight();

$('.button').click(function() {
  var active = $(this).toggleClass('active').hasClass('active');
  $(".change").css('padding-top', !active ? '0' : tagsHeight);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o1pbwfuo/6/)

Comment: Nice and simple, as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake while using .is and .not.
You need to address the class itself inclusive the dot at beginning.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

var tagsHeight = $('span').outerHeight();

$(".button").click(function (){
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', '0');
  }
  else if ($(this).not('.active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', tagsHeight);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06ek4fej/

---

By the way, the else-if request is nonsense.
If = true or if = false. Else If results the same as else.

```
$(".button").click(function (){
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', '0');
  }
  else {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', tagsHeight);
  }
});
```

Comment: `if ($(this).not('.active'))` will always be truthy and is not a valid check....no need for the extra `if()` anyway

Comment: Why not use `hasClass`?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, was pointing on that while you posted the comment ;)

Comment: @Chaaampy Good. Best because shortest solution was delivered by Rory. Give him the vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

On click you can check whether element has active class or not and there is no need to add two click methods on '.button'.

```
var tagsHeight = $('span').outerHeight();

$(".button").click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', '0');
  }
  else{
    $(".change").css('padding-top', tagsHeight);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Has class method for the check is active class exist or not.

```
$(".button").click(function (){
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(".change").css('padding-top', '0');
  }
  else{
    $(".change").css('padding-top', tagsHeight);
  }
});
```